# Keeping user input after error occurs

Tags: php, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

Here's the issue:

I created a drop down menu displaying security questions. One of the options is "Other". If "Other" is selected, a text box pops up beside the drop down menu prompting the user to input his own security question.

That all works great, but when  a user selects "Other" and an error occurs (in another part of the form), the scroll down menu still displays "Other", but the text box beside it disappears. Is there a way to keep the text box there if $_POST['question'] == other?

Here's an excerpt of my code, I can show more if it would be useful.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //initially hide the textbox
            $("#other_question").hide();
            $('#dd_question').change(function() {
              if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "0"){
                $("#other_question").show();
              }else{
                $("#other_question").hide();
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's the code for the drop down menu (in php)

```
$option_list = array(
        "1" => "In what city did your parents meet?",
        "2" => "What is your mother's maiden name?",
        "3" => "What was the name of your first pet?",
        "4" => "What is your oldest sibling's middle name?",
        "0" => "Other",
    );
foreach ($option_list as $option_id => $option) {
        echo "<option value = \"{$option_id}\" ";
        if ($option_id == $_POST['dd_question']) {
            echo " selected=\"selected\"";
        }
    echo ">{$option}</option>";
}
```

Thanks in advance for all suggestions!

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: From my experience with javascript, when an error occurs, it stops executing...so what is the error that's occurring?

Comment: Simple submit button, in HTML:  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

Comment: @Irfan, there is no error actually. I only want to know if it's possible to implement. The error would occur in the PHP part of the code. For example, malicious characters in the answer part of the form, etc. Something that would send an error message and stop the form from submitting

Comment: you could either set a `$_SESSION` var with it and then check if it `isset()` and place it. Or you can send it back in the url as a paramater.

Comment: isset() would work with a $_POST variable too (and then I wouldn't have to unset after). Except I don't know how to incorporate that in the jqeury part of the code. (That piece above is my first experience with jquery)

Comment: Yes, it's very possible.  Keep a copy of the form on the server side, with values filled in (or empty if the form is new).  Then develop a way to generate a form and send it back to the user with the values filled in.  If the form contains errors, mark the fields that have errors and note what's incorrect about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page load always check for other option 
instead of

```
//initially hide the textbox
            $("#other_question").hide();
```

do

```
//initially check the default value in dd_question
if($('#dd_question').find('option:selected').val() == "0"){
                $("#other_question").show();
              }else{
                $("#other_question").hide();
              }
```

Comment: @eigen93, by the way, no need to use `find('option:selected')`. If the `dd_question` id is for the `<select>` then `.val()` is enough.